# Use inotifywait to move file when it loads in dropbox folder

Tags: bash, centos, inotify

I'm trying to find a way to immediately move a file to another folder as soon as it appears in my dropbox on CentOS.

I have scoured the internet for some clues but I can't get any further than the fact that I need to use `inotify` to invoke a script which will process the file as it appears.

My BASH knowledge is very limited and I doubt I can write this in PHP.

In other words, how can I move a file to another folder as soon as it appears using `inotify`?

Comment: Is the name of the file consistently predictable? Or it's location? More detail would be helpful...

Comment: @jasonwryan It's a dropbox folder so the location is consistent. And it applies to *any* file dropped in that folder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a simple approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir=/home/ortix/Dropbox/new/
target=/home/ortix/movedfiles/

inotifywait -m "$dir" --format '%w%f' -e create |
    while read file; do
        mv "$file" "$target"
    done
```

With more details about the types of files you wanted to move, you could add some checking, logging etc...

Comment: I haven't been able to test either of the suggested answers. Things came up. Will do so ASAP!
I do have a question though. If I were to put this in a bash file and run it, I assume that it will run in the background, correct? I always have the feeling that a script is a 1 time run thing, but here inotifywait keeps running, correct?

Comment: listening on `create` event isn't correct, as you will do a `mv` on a file which may not be fully copied on disk. See @Gilles answer, using `close_write` event instead.

Comment: @fduff Seeing Gilles answer is *always* the correct thing to do...

Answer (score 20):

The command `inotifywait` prints a message each time a the contents of the specified directory change. You'll need to pick on the right event: not when the file is created, but when Dropbox has finished downloading it. I don't know exactly how Dropbox operates. If it writes to the file in its final place, listen to `close_write` events. If it writes to the file into a temporary location and then moves it into place, listen to `moved_to` events. Pass the options `-m -q` to `inotifywait` so that it keeps listening for events (by default, it only waits for the next event) and only prints relevant messages.

```
cd ~/Dropbox/myfolder
inotifywait -m -q -e close_write --format %f . | while IFS= read -r file; do
  cp -p "$file" /path/to/other/directory
done
```

Comment: This fails for files which include newlines in their names. I was unable to find a way to have `inotifywait` output null-terminated filenames. The best I could do was to use a character that's less likely than newline, for example `%f$'\001'`, and use `-d $'\001'` with `while IFS= read -r` or `xargs`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Yes, `inotifywait` is annoying that way. You can use something like `//%f`, as the file name will never contain a double slash as long as the path to watch doesn't; then the annoyance is on the parsing side.