# How can we know which user has created a file in a folder, using inotify and shell scripts?

Tags: scripting

Hello I need a little bit of help, please:

I have an excercise I want to do it is:

Create a script to monitor a DIRECTORY and for every file's creation append a new line in a register_file showing the date and hour, file's name and the name of the user who created the file.

I have tried:

```
inotifywait -m  -e create -o register_file --timefmt '%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M' --format '%T %f' ./
```

But how can I discover user's name?

Thank you.

My first intuition would be see /proc. I have studied man inotifywait inotifywatch and incron but nothing helps.

Comment: Please explain why using `ls -l` or `stat -f "%u"` or `stat -f "%Su"` doesn't suite you. Or you want to do everything by `inotifywait`?

Comment: Inotity can only tell you the name of the file that was created, not who created it. You can use Linux auditing to log who created a file.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**:
Not by any means an expert at `inotify`, I saw this as an opportunity to actually learn something new. With that out of the way, here is my approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

watchedDir="toWatch"

inotifywait -m "$watchedDir" -e create |
    while read -r file; do
        name=$(stat --format %U $file 2>/dev/null) 
        date=$(stat --format %y $file 2>/dev/null)
        fileName=${file/* CREATE /}
        echo "File: '$fileName' Creator: $name Date: ${date%.*}"
    done
```

Upon execution:

```
./watchDir.sh 
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

When I add a file to the directory `toWatch` from another terminal:

```
touch toWatch/a_file
```

...this is the output I get:

```
./watchDir.sh 
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
File: 'a_file' Creator: maulinglawns Date: 2016-12-10 12:29:42
```

And, adding another file...

```
touch toWatch/another_file
```

Gives...

```
./watchDir.sh 
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
File: 'a_file' Creator: maulinglawns Date: 2016-12-10 12:29:42
File: 'another_file' Creator: maulinglawns Date: 2016-12-10 12:31:15
```

Of course, if you want the output redirected to a file, you will have to implement that part.

This is based on @jasonwryan's post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86292/191550). But I haven't figured out the `--format` option for `inotifywait` yet. It's on my TODO list, therefore I choose to use `stat` instead.

Comment: just add >> output_file after the "echo" and that's what he wanted

Comment: @I-V Yes, but I believe OP can handle that part.

Comment: . I have learned what menas '-r' as an option in a while read statement, and it means: do not allow backlashes escape any character. I think it is needed because file will contain them and bash could misunderstands those. Also, ${file/* CREATE /} means remove whatever goes beyond whatever CREATE, in the file string, replacing it with the empty string. Finally, I suppose ${date%.*} means to remove the shortest match from the back of date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script which you can run and will give you the owner.
Instead of echo the owner you can write it the the register_file

```
#! /bin/bash

export fCreation=$(tail -1 ./register_file) #get the newest file creation documentation
export fName=${fCreation##* } #get the last word, which is the file name

export details=$(ls -al | grep $fName)

export owner=${details#* } #removes the file's permissions
owner=${owner#* }
owner=${owner#* }
owner=${owner%% *}

echo $owner
```

actually if you use `stat --format=%U $fName` you will get the owner easily.

EDIT:

From man 7 inotify:

"Limitations and caveats-
       The inotify API provides no information about the user or process  that"
       triggered the inotify event.

Comment: Breaks if you have a filename that contains a space. (Lots of mine do.)

Comment: so parse it as I parsed the owner... remove all the words before the filename